# Determine if a given type can currently be resolved by a Castle Windsor container

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a scenario where I need to know if a specific type can currently be resolved by a Windsor container. The wrinkle is that this type has dependencies. So I have a `ProductRepository` class that implements `IRefDataRepository` and depends on `IProductDataProvider`. I need to know if I can successfully resolve `IRefDataRepository` from the container.

I tried using `IKernel.HasComponent(typeof(IRefDataRepository))` `IKernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(IRefDataRepository))` both of which return `ProductRepository` even there is no `IProductDataProvider` registered. (So `IWindsorContainer.Resolve(typeof(IRefDataRepository))` will throw)

My current solution is to write an extension method that actually tries to resolve the type (via `IWindsorContainer.Resolve(IRefDataRepository)`), catches the exception, and returns true if the type resolves and false otherwise. But I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong.

You should have divided your program into two explicit parts:

- setup
- actual code

You register things in setup, then run the actual code where you can resolve stuff. If you can't resolve it, you have a bug in your setup code.

The 2nd part of the code should have no knowledge of the container, and polling the container is a big code smell.

Now, having said that, when you absolutely have to do it for some reason, get a handler for the component you need, and check it's state (`handler.CurrentState`). If it's `Valid` your component is safe to be resolved. **Opposite does not have to be true though!**

Comment: This works for the posted scenario, but it doesn't work if I'm using a factory method that takes an argument. handler.CurrentState is valid, but it still can't resolve as the factory method can't get the argument it needs.

Comment: I would also say that all of this code is the setup side of an ASP.NET MVC application. I'm using a custom controller factory so that I can use Windsor to resolve controller dependencies, and I want to know which controllers will succeed and which won't up front, so I can control which routes to register. I don't want to give access to controllers that won't work.

Comment: You're doing it wrong then. You should test to make sure **all** your controllers are properly configured and available as you register them. You want to workaround an issue in your code instead of fixing it.